# TreeView or ListView without column title bar

Tags: gtk, gtk3

Is there a way to show data in TreeView or ListView without column title bar?

Comment: No code needed. Question is simple and enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you talk about column title bar without showing any code makes me think that you are asking about Header.

If so, then this is the function you need:

```
gtk_tree_view_set_headers_visible()
```

Here is with `headers_visible` set to TRUE (which is default):

[image]

And here is with `headers_visible` set to FALSE:

[image]

And here is an example Code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget    *create_window ( void );
GtkWidget    *create_scrolled_window ( void );
GtkWidget    *create_tree_view ( void );
GtkListStore *create_list_store ( void );

int main ( void )
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *scrolled_window;
    GtkWidget *tree_view;

    /// ***
    gtk_init ( NULL, NULL );

    /// ***
    window = create_window();

    /// ***
    ///scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new ( NULL, NULL );
    scrolled_window = create_scrolled_window ( );
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_kinetic_scrolling ( GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW ( scrolled_window ), TRUE );
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_capture_button_press ( GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW ( scrolled_window ), TRUE );

    /// ***
    tree_view = create_tree_view ( );
    gtk_container_add ( GTK_CONTAINER ( scrolled_window ), tree_view );
    gtk_container_add ( GTK_CONTAINER ( window ), scrolled_window );

    /// ***
    gtk_widget_show_all ( window );

    // ***
    gtk_widget_show_all ( window );
    gtk_main ();
}

GtkWidget *create_window ( void )
{
    GtkWidget *window;

    /// ***
    window = gtk_window_new ( GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL );
    gtk_window_set_default_size ( GTK_WINDOW ( window ), 150, 150 );
    gtk_container_set_border_width ( GTK_CONTAINER ( window ), 5 );

    /// ***
    g_signal_connect ( window, "delete_event", G_CALLBACK ( gtk_main_quit ), NULL );

    /// ***
    return window;
}

GtkWidget *create_scrolled_window ( void )
{
    GtkWidget *scrolled_window;

    /// ***
    scrolled_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new ( NULL, NULL );
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_kinetic_scrolling ( GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW ( scrolled_window ), TRUE );
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_capture_button_press ( GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW ( scrolled_window ), TRUE );

    /// ***
    return scrolled_window;
}

GtkListStore *create_list_store ( void )
{
    GtkListStore *list_store;
    list_store = gtk_list_store_new ( 1, G_TYPE_STRING );

    /// ***
    for ( gint i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        GtkTreeIter iter;
        gchar *label = g_strdup_printf ( "Row number %d", i );

        /// ***
        gtk_list_store_append ( list_store, &iter );
        gtk_list_store_set ( list_store, &iter, 0, label, -1 );

        /// ***
        g_free ( label );
    }

    return list_store;
}

GtkWidget *create_tree_view ( void )
{
    GtkWidget       *tree_view;
    GtkCellRenderer *renderer;
    GtkListStore    *store;

    /// ***
    tree_view = gtk_tree_view_new ();
    store     = create_list_store();

    /// ***
    renderer = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new ();
    g_object_set ( renderer, "editable", TRUE, NULL );

    /// **
    gtk_tree_view_insert_column_with_attributes ( GTK_TREE_VIEW ( tree_view ),
            0, "This is the Title",
            renderer,
            "text", 0,
            NULL );

    /// ***
    gtk_tree_view_set_model ( GTK_TREE_VIEW ( tree_view ), GTK_TREE_MODEL ( store ) );
    g_object_unref ( store );

    /// ***
    gtk_tree_view_set_headers_visible ( GTK_TREE_VIEW ( tree_view ), FALSE );

    /// ***
    return tree_view;
}
```

Comment: In am happy to hear that. By the way you can take a look at my [GTK3 Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/c/MichaelB-GTK/playlists). Maybe you find something useful for you there.

Comment: @Michi is the raw code available somewhere ? Its hard to type all this manually in when following your tutorials ...

Comment: @Programmer I am sorry to tell you but I was working a lot on those videos. You will need to check them.